# What is the difference between "missing function level access control" and "privilege escalation"?

Tags: web-application, privilege-escalation

I was going through a web application from my account and I was able to view some confidential information about my other account. I want to know if this is a case of missing function level access control or privilege escalation.

Say my URL is: `www.example.com/user1/info/1` This URL contains my profile information. Now, I change this URL to `www.example.com/user1/info/2` This gives info about the profile of another user which should not be accessible to me.

Comment: This is standard behavior for many web platforms which my default do not have any access control enabled. If you want to implement access control you should say more about the platform used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above case is falling under **missing function level access control**. You can see private information of another user. That is usual in a missing access control. As you can again look at this url `www.example.com/user1/info/2` .
For more information have a look at it [OWASP TOP 10 2013](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A7-Missing_Function_Level_Access_Control).

Answer (score 1):

**Privilege Escalation** means that your rights have been elevated throughout the environment. In your scenario, your rights have not been changed. The problem is that everyone can see everyone's data. This scenario is a classic **access control** problem.